# How do I get the last push of an image with the x.x tag if I already have an old push of an x.x image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-registry

In 2019, I made a pull image of Python 3.6. After that, I was sure that the image was self-updating (I did not use it actively, I just hoped that the latest pushes themselves were pulled from the repository or something like that), but I was surprised when I accidentally noticed the download/creation date is 2019.

**Q**: How does image pull work? Are there flags so that the layer hash/its relevance* is checked every time the image is built? Perhaps there is a way to set this check through the docker daemon config file? Or do I have to delete the base image every time to get a new image?

**What I want**: So that every time I build my images, the base image is checked for the last push (publication of image) in the docker hub repository.

**Note**: I'm talking about images with an identical tag. Also, I'm not afraid to re-build my images, there is no purpose to preserve them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitly `docker pull` the image to get updates.  For your custom images, there are `docker build --pull` and `docker-compose build --pull` options that will pull the base image (though there is not a "pull" option for `docker-compose up --build`).

Without this, Docker will never check for updates for an image it already has.  If your Dockerfile starts `FROM python:3.6` and you already have a local image with that name and tag, Docker just uses it without contacting Docker Hub.  If you don't have it then Docker will pull it, once, and then you'll have it locally.

The other thing to watch for is that the updates do eventually stop.  If you look at the [Docker Hub `python` image page](https://hub.docker.com/_/python) you'll notice that there are no longer rebuilds for Python 3.5.  If you pin to a very specific patch version, the automated builds generally only build the latest patch version for each supported minor version; if your image is `FROM python:3.6.11` it will never get updates because 3.6.12 is the latest 3.6.x version.